# Haskell:Could not deduce (Floating t) arising from a use of `cos'

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and I tried to implement some quantum gates based on resources that I found on Internet.
For now, I successfully implemented Z-gate,X-gate,H-gate but I have a problem implementing the rotation gate.

```
U = [[cos t  -sin t] 
     [sin t  cos t ]]
```

The code that I wrote:

```
type Vector a = [a]
type Matrix a = [Vector a]
vectorToComplex :: Integral a => Vector a -> Vector (Complex Double)
vectorToComplex = map (\i -> fromIntegral i:+0.0)

matrixToComplex :: Integral a => Matrix a -> Matrix (Complex Double)
matrixToComplex = map vectorToComplex
--Z Gate
gateZ :: Matrix (Complex Double)
gateZ = matrixToComplex [[1,0],[0,-1]]
```

I tried to implement the gateR ( rotation gate) in the same way I implemented the Z-gate:

```
gateR :: Integral t => t -> Matrix (Complex Double)
gateR t = matrixToComplex [[cos t,-sin t],[sin t,cos t]]
```

but I have the next error and I don't really understand it ( I'm still learning the language).

```
Could not deduce (Floating t) arising from a use of `cos'
    from the context (Integral t)
      bound by the type signature for
                 gateR :: Integral t => t -> Matrix (Complex Double)
      at quantum.hs:66:8-44
    Possible fix:
      add (Floating t) to the context of
        the type signature for
          gateR :: Integral t => t -> Matrix (Complex Double)
    In the expression: cos t
    In the expression: [cos t, - sin t]
    In the first argument of `matrixToComplex', namely
      `[[cos t, - sin t], [sin t, cos t]]'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cos` and `sin` can only take a `Floating` argument, yet the type signature for `gateR` says that `t` is an `Integral` type, and not all `Integral`s are `Floating`.  Either change the type signature for `gateR` or convert `t` within `gateR` using `fromIntegral`.

Answer (score 4):

Your functions only demand the constraint of `Integral t` thus you need to convert your `t` with `fromIntegral` and possibly an explicit type signature so you can apply sine and cosine. E.g.

```
cos (fromIntegral t :: Double)
```